# Receiving updated value from recursive call

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I have a DFS function which collects *entry* and *leave* times of vertices. Unfortunately, I am unable to receive a proper value for *leave* time, because it is not connected with the value from recursive call.

```
void DFS_visit(int i, vector<int> Adj[], int visited[], int p[], int entry[], int leave[], int t)
{
    visited[i] = 1;
    entry[i] = t;
    cout << i << " ";
    for (auto u : Adj[i])
    {
        if (!visited[u])
        {
            p[u] = i;
            DFS_visit(u, Adj, visited, p, entry, leave, t++);
        }
    }
    leave[i] = t++;
}
```

It is obviously an auxiliary function, I also have a "main" DFS function:

```
void DFS(vector<int> Adj[], int n)
{
    int visited[n], p[n], entry[n], leave[n];
    int t = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        visited[i] = 0;
        p[i] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!visited[i])
        {
            DFS_visit(i, Adj, visited, p, entry, leave, t);
        }
    }
```

Could you please tell me how I am supposed to pass the updated value of *leave* time to leave[i]? Thanks in advance!

Comment: pass `t` by reference

Comment: or make it a return value (`t = DFS_visit(u, Adj, visited, p, entry, leave, t + 1);`).